# JavaScript function disables the whole JS code

Tags: javascript

I've placed a  tag in the header without any previous script tags and in it, the code bellow:

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
            alert("asd");

            function displayPic(str){
                if(str=""){
                    document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML="<img src="" class='slider'/>";
                }

                if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
                        document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "gallery.php?q="+str, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
```

The purpose of the alert on top is to test if the script is executing. As it stands, it is not. There's no popup alert saying "asd", it's as if there's no JS code at all, but when I remove the whole function displayPic and leave alert("asd"), it works just fine. I can't spot anything wrong with this simple piece of code and I've spend good 30 minutes trying to figure out what could cause this, but my problem solving abilities fruited no results.

This is a PHP page, btw, running it on a localhost using WAMP.

Comment: You have bad quoting inside `innerHTML="<img src="" class='slider'/>"`  Change the `src=""` to `src=''` but know also that an empty `src` attribute will probably cause another HTTP request to the current page.

Comment: Jesus, you're right. I'm an idiot...

Comment: You probably also mean `if (str == "")`, with a double equals sign. Otherwise you are *assigning* `""` to `str`, overwriting your string and ensuring the `if` is **never** entered.

Comment: Ouch. Sounds like somebody needs more coffee...

Comment: One more cup can't hurt

Comment: JSLint or JSHint, hook it into your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an interesting online resource: http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php

Pasting your code in, it found three possible problems:

1. The quotes issue (it automatically "assumed" you wanted to escape the quotes)
2. The "assignment instead of comparison"
3. A possible missing `;`

```
 1  <script type="text/javaScript">
 2              alert("asd");
 3  
 4              function displayPic(str){
 5                  if(str=""){
    =========================^
    warning: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?
 6                      document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML="<img src=\"\" class='slider'/>";
 7                  }
 8  
 9                  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
10                      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
11                  }
12  
13                  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
14                      if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
15                          document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
16                      }
17                  }
18                  xmlhttp.open("GET", "gallery.php?q="+str, true);
    ================^
    lint warning: missing semicolon
19                  xmlhttp.send();
20              }
21          </script>
```

There may be better resources, but this is clearly something you might want to do in future before asking the community for help with your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

1. The line:

   ```
   document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML="<img src="" class='slider'/>";
   ```

   has HTML double quotes (`" "`) inside JS double quotes (`" "`). This results in a syntax error, explaining why none of your code gets run. Try:

   ```
   document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML="<img src='' class='slider'/>";
   ```
2. This won't cause an error, but you probably also mean `if (str == "")`, with a double equals sign. Otherwise you are assigning `""` to `str`, overwriting your string and ensuring the if is never entered.

Working example at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5hbL/2/)